# Shuffling table rows using PGF

Tags: pgfplotstable, random-numbers

Does anyone know how to get table with rows randomly shuffled (using `\pgfplotstabletypeset` from .dat-type file)?

My current code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{myfile.dat} %% <-- create simple .dat-file (the real one is bigger!)
A & B & C
q & w & e
r & t & y
\end{filecontents}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=&,
    string type]{myfile.dat} %% <-- here should be shuffled rows
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a dirty one: we can say that you want to "sort" the rows in an unpredictable way. So

- tell P<sub><sup>GFPLOTS</sup></sub>T<sub><sup>ABLE</sup></sub> to sort the rows
- mess up P<sub><sup>GFPLOTS</sup></sub>T<sub><sup>ABLE</sup></sub>'s function of comparing rows.

Now we end up with a messily sorted table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{filecontents,pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
    \begin{filecontents}{myfile.dat}
        A & B & C
        q & w & e
        r & t & y
        1 & 2 & 3
        4 & 5 & 6
        7 & 8 & 9
    \end{filecontents}

    \pgfkeys{
        /pgfplots/float </.style={%
            /pgfplots/iflessthan/.code args={##1##2##3##4}{%
                \pgfmathrnd
                \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt<0.5pt
                    ##3%
                \else
                    ##4%
                \fi
            }%
        }
    }
    \pgfmathsetseed{287252}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=&,string type,sort]{myfile.dat}
\end{document}
```

## A Saver way

As @percusse suggests, one need not redefine `float <` -- just define a new comparing function with a new name. The output is the same as above.

```
\pgfkeys{
    /pgfplots/random/.style={%
        /pgfplots/iflessthan/.code args={##1##2##3##4}{%
            \pgfmathrnd
            \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt<0.5pt
                ##3%
            \else
                ##4%
            \fi
        }%
    },
    /pgfplots/table/sort cmp=random
}
```

Comment: You can make a random integer sequence, add it as a column and sort on that. At least you can define a new `sort cmp`